# How can I center a SpanLabel's text in CodenameOne?

Tags: codenameone

Contrary to what is shown in the sample usage section of the SpanLabel [documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/SpanLabel.html), where the text is centered by default, the text of my SpanLabel is left-aligned (see screenshot from simulator below). How can I center it?

[image].

Answer (score 3):

`SpanLabel` has a `setTextUIID` method that allows you to determine the UIID of the text within. This defaults to `Label` for ease of use but you can change that to anything you want and define that to be centered.

Comment: Ok. I guessed as much. In that case, the sample code in the documentation is misleading as there is no mention of this fact there. I propose that the documentation be updated to reflect the default behavior.

Comment: I think the fix should be to the image, not sure why it's center aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Programatically this worked for me (aligning to the right):

```
spLabel3.getTextAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.RIGHT);
```